# How to use align between elements of an array in assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture

Good afternoon, I have a question about arrays in assembler since I have a half-word array with five elements and I need to separate them so that, when compiling and executing, I don't get two elements in a row (as if it were a word) and take me only one.

For example, in the array 128,32,100, -39,124 (currently decimal notation) when executed in assembler it returns 128 and 32 in hexadecimal in a single string and I would need 128 to go in one string and 32 in another.

I've read about using the align directive but can't get it into my code to make it work properly.

```
.data
var2:   .hword  128,32,100,-39,124
        .align 4

.text

.global main

main:   mov     r0, #5
        mov     r1, #0
        ldr     r2, =var2

bucle:  ldr     r3, [r2], #4
        add     r1, r1, r3
        subs    r0, r0, #1
        bne     bucle
        bx      lr
```

Comment: `LDR` is a full word load. If you have half words, use `LDRSH`.

Comment: @Jester ldr before bucle or at beginning of bucle?

Comment: At `bucle` because that is loading the elements. Also a half word is 2 bytes so change the `4` to `2`.

Comment: @Jester okay and... to change a word for a byte?

Comment: `LDRSB` and use `1`.

Comment: If you want each element to be word-sized so you can load it with `ldr`, use `.long` instead of `.hword`.  That would be equivalent to using `.balign 4` / `.hword 128` / `.balign 4` / `.hword 32` / etc.  (Except negative values would only fill the low 16 bits)